# Why is my function not accepting a double pointer?

Tags: c, function, hash, double-pointer

I have a hash table declared as follows:

```
node* table[26];
```

And below is the function supposed to free that hash table:

```
bool unload(void)
{
    // TODO
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
    {
        free_table(&table[i]);
        if (table[i] != NULL)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}


void free_table(node** hash)
{
    if (*hash == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }
    free_table((*hash) -> next);
    free(*hash);
    *hash = NULL;
}
```

The problem is whenever I try to compile, I get the following error:

```
error: incompatible pointer types passing 'node **' (aka 'struct node **') to parameter of type 'node *' (aka 'struct node *'); remove & [-Werror,-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
free_table(&table[i]);
           ^~~~~~~~~
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Related, after bemusing the novelty of doing this recursively, do it iteratively instead. It will likely be faster, and as a bonus you don't run the risk of blowing out your activation stack on excessively large chains.

Comment: What is the structure of a `node`?  How do you allocate the data for `table`?  This looks like a trie structure — is this from the CS50 course, perchance?  If so, the recursion is probably necessary, but the fact that the questions need to be asked emphasizes the importance of creating an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) — or MRE or whatever name SO now uses) or an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)) — the same idea by a different name.

Comment: Style guide: the dot `.` and arrow `->` operators bind very tightly
because they are [postfix operators](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.3).
They should not be written with spaces around them.
Writing `(*hash) -> next` is not idiomatic C and indicates that the coder
is a tyro (newbie).  Use `(*hash)->next`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler  I use the space per the lectures I have been taken, and it's been working just fine.

Comment: It works.  It just looks like you don't know how to code in C, though.  And if your lecturers write code with the spaces around the arrow and dot operators, then it looks like they don't know how to code in C either (which is depressingly probable).  As I said, it is a style guideline — it is not a syntax error.  Look at the [C standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html) or the K&R book, or other reputable books — they don't use spaces around the arrow or dot operators.  Neither should you.  (Show me a book with spaces around these operators, and I can show you a non-reputable book!)

Comment: C compilers work on tokens, so space is insignificant, but there are operators that should have spaces around them and some don't as a stylistic choice in programming guidelines

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`free_table` is recursively calling `free_table` again in line 4 of the definition of `free_table` as

```
free_table((*hash) -> next);
```

Also, did you declare `free_table` as

```
free_table(node ** hash);
```

(in a header file or otherwise) before defining it here? I suspect that you might have made a mistake in the function declaration, which resulted in the compilation error.

I am guessing that the type of the struct member `next` is `node *`, which means that the type of `(*hash) -> next` is also `node *`. Changing that line to the following should work, i.e. take the address of `(*hash) -> next`.

```
free_table(&((*hash) -> next));
```

Comment: I agree. Edited my answer to mention a possible source of compilation error.

Comment: Likely to be the problem as the func is used before it is defined in the excerpt we are given to see.